# Can anyone explain Underscore's precompilation in _.template?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I read Underscore's docs, find in [`_.template`](http://underscorejs.org/#template):

> Precompiling your templates can be a big help when debugging errors you can't reproduce. This is because precompiled templates can provide line numbers and a stack trace, something that is not possible when compiling templates on the client. The source property is available on the compiled template function for easy precompilation

I wonder what it means and how it's used.

I write the code below:

```
<div>
  <ul class="list">
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>orange</li>
    <li class="last-item">peach</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="underscore.js"></script>

<script type="text/template" id="tpl">
  <ul class="list">
    <%_.each(obj, function(e, i, a){%>
      <% if (i === a.length - 1) %>
        <li class="last-item"><%=e.name%></li>
      <% else %>
        <li><%=e.name%></li>
    <%})%>
  </ul>
</script>

<script>
var data = [{name: "apple"}, {name: "orange"}, {name: "peach"}];
var compiled = _.template(document.getElementById("tpl").innerHTML);
var str = compiled(data);
document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = str;
</script>
```

It works well, and in my opinion, when I miss an `>` in the template, by precompiling it will tell me which line I miss the `>`, is that right? And how to do a demo? The following code may not work if straightly put, so how to make it useful?

```
<script>
  JST.project = <%= _.template(jstText).source %>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JST is a **server-side** thing, not client-side. This mean that you compile Unserscore template on **server side** by some server-side script and save the result in a file. Then use this file as **compiled** Unserscore template.

Comment: so it's a totally **function** in the client side, and we can see the error line when the function is something wrong with?

Comment: it's an object with Unserscore template methods. With precompiled template the benefit is that you can catch the **real location** of error in template. With client-side compiled template you always get error location in Unserscore source, not in template.

Comment: Clear explanation! One more question, is that familiar with the usage of Node.js as a middle between front and end?

Comment: @ZichiHan It's unclear what you mean. Using Node.js to precompile Unserscore templates?

Comment: I once learn that using Node.js between front and end, I am not familiar with Node.js, after your explanation, I guess maybe it;s feasible using Node.js to precompile Unserscore templates? err maybe I still need data from the backend.. maybe it's another problem for me.

Comment: @ZichiHan Sure, you can use Node.js to precompile Unserscore templates. There are plenty of tools in [Node](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/jst) as well as in other server-side languages.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to embrace the angular brackets. Just do the following:

```
<script>
    const yourData = {};
    JST.project = _.template(jstText)(yourData);
</script>
```

That should to the trick :)

Comment: by using this way, what's the difference between my code?